# How do I create sequentially numbered file names in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I need a script that will create a file with the next file in a sequence. Each execution of the script should only create one file and the script could be run zero or more times on any given day. The files should be named after the current date in format `%y%m%d` with the second file having `-01` appended, the third file to be created on a given date would have `-02` etc. For example:

```
20170125.txt  // first file create on the day.
20170125-01.txt // 2nd file
20170125-02.txt // 3rd file
```

So far I've got this super basic script that creates my first daily file but I'm stumped as to how to do the incremental numbering after that.

```
#! /bin/bash

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
touch "$DATE.txt"
```

Comment: Are you trying to split up a log or something? What's the real aim?

Comment: I'm creating some web pages and I just want a quick script to save me the hassle of creating a matching HTML, JS and CSS file. I just want to do `./newsketch.sh` and have all the boilerplate ready to go.

Comment: Ah, ok. Let me think then.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
today=$( date +%Y%m%d )   # or: printf -v today '%(%Y%m%d)T' -1
number=0

fname=$today.txt

while [ -e "$fname" ]; do
    printf -v fname '%s-%02d.txt' "$today" "$(( ++number ))"
done

printf 'Will use "%s" as filename\n' "$fname"
touch "$fname"
```

`today` gets today's date, and we initialise our counter, `number`, to zero and create the initial filename as the date with a `.txt` suffix.

Then we test to see if the filename already exists. If it does, increment the counter and create a new filename using `printf`. Repeat until we no longer have a filename collision.

The format string for the `printf`, `%s-%02d.txt`, means "a string followed by a literal dash followed by a zero-filled two-digit integer and the string `.txt`". The string and the integer is given as further arguments to `printf`.

The `-v fname` puts the output of `printf` into the variable `fname`.

The `touch` is just there for testing.

This will generate filenames like

```
20170125.txt
20170125-01.txt
20170125-02.txt
20170125-03.txt
```

etc. on subsequent runs.

Comment: Bonus points for the explanation.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `seq`. It can create number sequences in variety of ways, however you need to know total number of files.

E.g: You can try `seq -w 1 10`. It will create the sequence from `01` to `10`, then you can include it in a for loop:

```
for i in `seq -w 1 10`
do
  touch `date +%Y%m%d`-$i.txt
done
```

**Addendum for your latest question update:**

To accomplish what you want easily, you can create the first file with `-0`. On subsequent runs, you need to take the list of files, `sort` them, take the last one, `cut` it from last `-` and get the number, increment it and create the new file with that number.

Padding will need some more work though.

Comment: I've updated the question with a bit more info. The script should only create one file on each execution, the file should have the next number in the sequence.

Comment: There are more advanced facilities in Linux, like `logrotate`. They can do something similar automatically if you need. Your question needs some processing, so it may not be trivial with bash. That's why I asked the real reason.

Comment: @bayindirh `logrotate` is useful for rotating logs, but the question is about generating filenames, not rotating logfiles.

Comment: I know, in first iteration of the question, aim was not clear. So I asked the question owner and he clarified. Please see the comments under the question too. I just didn't delete my comment to left the thing up in the air.

Answer (score 3):

Something like...

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
filename="${DATE}.txt"
num=0
while [ -f $filename ]; do
    num=$(( $num + 1 ))
    filename="${DATE}-${num}.txt"
done
touch $filename
```

...should work. This creates filenames of the format DATE-1.txt, DATE-2.txt, DATE-3.txt, ..., DATE-10.txt, DATE-11.txt, etc. Changing that to DATE-01.txt etc is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Note that you should probably also make sure you don't call the script more than once concurrently, otherwise you'll have more than one script modifying things.

Side note: there is loads of software for managing multiple versions of a file. They're called "version control systems" (VCS), or "Source Control Management" (SCM). Git and subversion are pretty popular. I suggest you check them out, rather than reimplementing your own :-)

Comment: Please read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Comment: try `filename=$(printf "%s-%0d.txt" "$date" "$num")`

Comment: @glennjackman what that link points to is very true for variables of which you're not sure you'll know the contents, but not so for cases like these where (format of) the contents of the variable is known. In this script, $DATE is *always* YYYYMMDD, and $num is *always* a number. In that case, there are *no* security implications. If you think otherwise, please provide the proof. Is it bad style? Perhaps, but then shell scripts are bad style programming to begin with :-)

Comment: My view is that you follow best practices or you don't

Comment: well, we disagree then :)

Comment: That still becomes a bug when that code is copied or sourced from/into a context where `$IFS` could have been modified. Leaving the variable unquoted is still asking the shell to split+glob it which doesn't make any sense here.

Comment: You're reaching. The script as given doesn't modify `$IFS`.

Comment: Your `touch` command is outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: @sebath: yes, because we are *looking* for the first file that does not exist, so that we can then *create* it. We don't want to create *all* files, and touching all of them does not make sense. Please try to understand the script :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the counter value in an environment variable, you can use Bash arithmetic to generate the filename .... the $(( ctr+=1 )) increments the value of ctr, and substitutes the value in the filename string.

```
$ ctr=0
$ touch file-$(( ctr+=1 ))-name.txt
$ touch file-$(( ctr+=1 ))-name.txt
$ touch file-$(( ctr+=1 ))-name.txt
$ touch file-$(( ctr+=1 ))-name.txt
$ ls
file-1-name.txt  file-2-name.txt file-3-name.txt  file-4-name.txt
```